# Update record in Sencha Touch Data Store with Ajaxproxy

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm developing a simple form with Secha Touch. I have defined a DataStore for my model like this:

```
App.stores.shopinglists = new Ext.data.Store({
model: 'ShopingList',
autoLoad: false,

proxy: new Ext.data.AjaxProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost:2795/ShopingListService/',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'ResultData',
        totalProperty: 'Total',
        successProperty: 'Success'
    },
    writer: {
        encode: true,
        type: 'json'
    }

})
});
```

The view loads fine, and I can see a list of items and edit them. However, when I click the update button, I get the following error:
Uncaught Error: You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.

What I am missing here? The proxy has the url defined, but when update is invoked, it's undefined.

Edit: The button just call a controller action.

```
onSaveAction: function () {
    var model = this.getRecord();
    Ext.dispatch({
        controller: 'ShopingLists',
        action: (model.phantom ? 'save' : 'update'),
        data: this.getValues(),
        record: model,
        form: this
    });
},
```

The code executed by the controller is this:

```
update: function (params) {
    debugger;
    var tmpshopingList = new App.models.ShopingList(params.data);
    var errors = tmpshopingList.validate();
    if (errors.isValid()) {
        params.record.set(params.data);
        params.record.save();
        this.index();
    } else {
        params.form.showErrors(errors);
    }
},
```

Comment: Pleas post the code executed by your Update button

Comment: Hello:
Thanks for your replay.
I placed the code inside in my firs comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what is happening: The model knows it has a server proxy, but all of the configurations are not being copied over. Perhaps this is a bug with Sencha Touch 1.x.

Try putting the `proxy` configuration into your model, not your store.

Comment: rdougan, thanks for your help! I was fallowing a tutorial with Local Storage as repo and the same code worked fine. I placed the proxy config in model an it's posting!